# oracle post data

Tags: php, sql, oracle, plsql

I have a post data in php (array of data) and I need to pass it to oracle procedure, that accepts `table%ROWTYPE`.  How can I make a table of data to pass?

Here is code sample:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE restoraunt IS

    TYPE recipe_table IS TABLE OF recipes%ROWTYPE;
    PROCEDURE upsert_recipes(recipes recipe_table);

END restoraunt;

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY restoraunt IS

  PROCEDURE upsert_recipes(recipes recipe_table) IS
  BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('123');
  END;

END restoraunt;
```

As you can see, I need to pass recipe_table object. How can I make it with php? (I know, that it should be some kind of pl/sql code, but I don't get it)

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass a table of %rowtype into an Oracle procedure.

However, you can pass a table of an object type:

```
CREATE TYPE recipe_obj AS OBJECT 
    ( recipe_id NUMBER
    , recipe_text VARCHAR2(200)
    );

CREATE TYPE recipe_tbl AS TABLE OF recipe_obj;

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE restoraunt IS
    PROCEDURE upsert_reciptes ( recipes recipe_tbl);
END restoraunt;

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY restoraunt IS
    PROCEDURE upsert_recipes ( recipes recipe_tbl ) IS
    BEGIN
        dbms_output.put_line('123');
    END;
END restoraunt;
```

However, the only way that I know to pass this into Oracle from outside of Oracle is from Java.

If you use Oracle's JDeveloper Suite, you can autogenerate the necessary java classes after you create the object type and object table.  Then you can use Oracle's OJDBC library to pass the java objects into Oracle via an OracleCallableStatement.  A great reference book on this is R. M. Menon's [Expert Oracle JDBC Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/159059407X).